# Adb shell загрузка файла с устройства на ПК

Tags: android, adb

Здравствуйте, мне необходимо скачать файл с android устройства. Я, в режиме su, через командную строку, нахожу этот файл на устройстве, однако не знаю как его оттуда скачать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Попробовал я уже следующие команды:

```
adb pull /data/user/0/com.whatever.repeater/files/myfolder/dat.csv A:\MUSOR
adb shell su pull /data/user/0/com.whatever.repeater/files/myfolder/dat.csv A:\MUSOR
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же буду благодарен, если скажете, что делает данная команда, что она скачивает и куда она это сохраняет?

```
C:\Users\Oleg>adb pull su /data/user/0/com.whatever.repeater/files/myfolder/dat.csv
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

`adbd` на устройстве работает с правами пользователя `shell` (UID=2000). И если этот пользователь не имеет доступа к файлу - скачать его командой `adb pull` не получится. Есть два варианта - либо сначала скопировать файл в публичную директорию (типа `/data/local/tmp`) и потом скачать эту копию, либо (актуально для больших файлов) поменять права доступа ориганального файла, скачать и поменять права обратно:

```
adb shell su 0 cp /data/user/0/com.whatever.repeater/files/myfolder/dat.csv /data/local/tmp
adb shell su 0 chmod 666 /data/local/tmp/dat.csv
adb pull /data/local/tmp/dat.csv %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\
```

Для текстовых файлов также подойдет вариант:

```
adb shell su 0 cat /data/user/0/com.whatever.repeater/files/myfolder/dat.csv > %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\dat.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

adb pull /путьдофайла %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\

По сути куда скачивать надо указывать с обратными слешами

Как вариант есть софт [Android All In One Tool Kit](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2494319)

Comment: Не работает, пишет:
adb pull /data/user/0/com.whatever.repeater/files/myfolder/dat.csv %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\

remote object '/data/user/0/com.whatever.repeater/files/myfolder/dat.csv' does not exist

Comment: Прежде всего удостоверьтесь что путь до файла правильный. Плюс есть ли у Вас эта папка на компьютере в профиле пользователя. Или укажите полный путь.
По поводу Remote object,дайте права на папку: chmod 777 data
Также есть ещё вариант:<br>
adb shell "su -c 'cat filepath'" > file.ext